# ERROR shard-manager: text_generation_launcher: Shard process was signaled to shutdown with signal 7 rank=1

Tags: docker, gpu, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, llama

Does anybody have an idea to solve this problem or is there something I dont fully understand?

Backround/Expl:

I try to run a HF TGI Inference on 3 shareds (--num-shard 3). On 2 shardes it is going well.When I try to distribute the modell on 3 shardes, it does not load.

I tried also the latest version of text-generation-inference but somehow it isnt laoding anything. No metter if 1 sh or 2 sh or 3 sh.

SetUP:

Ubuntu 22.04.
Docker Docker version 24.0.7
Cuda 12.3
Driver 545.23.08
GPU 3 X rtx 3090 ftw3

Command:

docker run --gpus all -it --name model_inference1 --network  xyz-network -p 1212:80 -v /stor:/data   ghcr.io/huggingface/text-generation-inference:1.1.1   --model-id /data/models/em_german_70b_v01-GPTQ_40gb  --port 80 --quantize gptq  --sharded true --num-shard 2 --max-input-length 4095  --max-total-tokens 4096   --max-batch-prefill-tokens 4095

Error:

You are using a model of type llama to instantiate a model of type . This is not supported for all configurations of models and can yield errors. rank=1
2023-12-10T14:44:56.251513Z ERROR shard-manager: text_generation_launcher: Shard process was signaled to shutdown with signal 7 rank=1
2023-12-10T14:44:56.346250Z ERROR text_generation_launcher: Shard 1 failed to start
2023-12-10T14:44:56.346297Z  INFO text_generation_launcher: Shutting down shards
2023-12-10T14:44:56.414527Z  INFO shard-manager: text_generation_launcher: Shard terminated rank=0
2023-12-10T14:44:56.475884Z  INFO shard-manager: text_generation_launcher: Shard terminated rank=2
Error: ShardCannotStart

Is llama that type of model, that isnt able to run on 3 gpus? weired.

I tried

- different Model-Versions
- different TGI Versions
- deactivate EXLLAMA